# How to make "drawable" files accessible through the code

Tags: android

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Context context, String filename){
        AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream buf = null;
        try {
            buf = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/black_circle.png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

when I use the code above the system gives the following error

```
09-27 12:33:44.470: W/System.err(18554): java.io.FileNotFoundException: drawable/black_circle.png
09-27 12:33:44.470: W/System.err(18554):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
09-27 12:33:44.470: W/System.err(18554):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
09-27 12:33:44.470: W/System.err(18554):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
```

I'm running the code on a Samsung Galaxy, through Eclipse. How to make this work?

I need to change the file name dynamically.

Comment: inside the assets dir do you put a directory named drawable and iside it the png file?

Comment: i have a directory called "res". Nothing called "assets". Inside res there is a folder called drawable.

Comment: then you should follow what @Nunu suggests.

Comment: @what's your purpose? What do you want to achive?

Comment: are u suggesting me to create an "assets" folder inside the android project?. Its not working, i need to load the file name dynamically

Comment: what does dynamically means for you?

Comment: as its shown is method, if some one pass a file name (a String) then method should return the Bitmap of that file.

Comment: then you can not store inside drawable. You have to store it inside the SD card (for instance).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17224/discussion-between-dinesh707-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way :

```
int image_id = getResources().getIdentifier("imagename", "drawable", getPackageName());

image.setBackgroundResource(image_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

to open images under drawable folder:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.black_circle);
```

Comment: a bit of comment would be appriciated

Comment: I need to change  "drawable/black_circle.png" dynamically. So your suggestion is not working that way. tx

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.addto);
```

if you want to create bitmap from the drawable image then you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.black_circle);
```